# Split the existing content into three columns or parts

Tags: html, css

I have the following code which displays everything vertically:

```css
.scanTitle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

div.form {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

form {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: left;
}

.checkboxes label {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.checkboxes label:first-of-type {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.requiredFieldLabel {
  border: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 2px;
  color: #333366;
  font-family: "verdana";
  font-size: small;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: right;
}

.requiredFieldLabel::before {
  content: "* ";
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="scanTitle">Employee Title</div>
  <div class="form">
    <form id="copysomeForm" action="/abc/employee.htm" method="POST">
      <div>
        <label class="requiredFieldLabel">Employee ID</label>
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label class="requiredFieldLabel">Delay Reason for All Employees</label>
        <select id="reasonSelect" name="delayReason" onchange="reasonChanged()">
          <option value="">-No Selection-</option>
          <option value="Late Payment">Late Payment</option>
          <option value="Options Test One">Options Test One</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <label>
            <input id="sendEmailAlert1" name="sendEmailAlert" type="checkbox" />
            Send Email
          </label>
        </div>
        <div><label>Subject:</label></div>
        <div>
          <input
            id="empSubject"
            name="empSubject"
            type="text"
            value=""
            size="35"
            maxlength="100"
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Message:</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <textarea
            id="empMessage"
            name="empMessage"
            rows="5"
            cols="35"
          ></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>CC:</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input
            id="empCC"
            name="empCC"
            type="text"
            value=""
            size="35"
            maxlength="100"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>
          <input id="topList" name="list1" type="checkbox" />
          Employee Sign
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="checkboxes">
        <label>
          <input id="topList" name="list1" type="checkbox" />
          Employee Decision
        </label>
        <label>
          <input id="list1" name="list2" type="checkbox" />
          Go Right
        </label>
        <label>
          <input id="list2" name="list3" type="checkbox" />
          Turn Off the Switch
        </label>
        <label>
          <input id="list3" name="list4" type="checkbox" />
          Go Left
        </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <label>Note I</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <textarea id="empNote1" name="empNote1" rows="5" cols="35"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <label>Note II:</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <textarea id="empNote2" name="empNote2" rows="5" cols="35"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <label>Comment:</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <textarea
            id="empComment"
            name="empComment"
            rows="5"
            cols="35"
          ></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label class="requiredFieldLabel">Tag</label>
        <select
          id="reasontagSelect"
          name="tagReason"
          onchange="reasonTagChanged()"
        >
          <option value="">-No Selection-</option>
          <option value="Tag1">Tag1</option>
          <option value="Tag2">Tag2</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm looking to split it into three columns type of sections as shown in the image below:

[image]

I was thinking about using `float: left` for the "Send Email" check box and the "Subject", "Message", and "CC" text inputs, so that they display on the left; and using `float: right` for the "Note II" and "Comment" text inputs and the "Tag" drop-down; but I'm not sure how to put the checkboxes and "Note I" in the middle. Am I thinking about it correctly?

**Note:** I just came up with these 3 columns idea as I want to have the whole page covered with some content and not show it vertically.

Comment: What about Flexbox or Grid?

Comment: In case of Flexbox , is using `justify-content: left;` for left side content, `justify-content: center;` for center content and `justify-content: right;` for right content  going to be good to start with? I haven't used either of those to be honest and hence wondering.

Comment: Can you change the markup at all? If so, this can be done very easily with Grid.

Comment: Yes. That's okay I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) to arrange all the sections.

Changes I made:

- Set `box-sizing: border-box` on all elements.
- Wrapped the sections in `div`s with appropriate classes.
- Changed the `form`'s `display` to `grid`.
- Added `grid-template-areas` to the `form`.
- Set the `grid-area` on each of the sections.
- Set `justify-self: center` on the top section to center align it.
- Used Flexbox on the top section to right-align the contents.
- Set the same width on the two inputs in the top section. I've used `20ch`, but you can use whatever is appropriate.

I have added borders to show element boxes.
Also, I removed the `<div class="form">` and its styling. The styling was unnecessary, and I could see no purpose in keeping the `div`, as this is intended to be an example, not a copy-pasteable solution.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "top top top"
    "left center right";
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: left;
}

.grid-top {
  grid-area: top;
  justify-self: center;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
  
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.grid-top input,
.grid-top select {
  width: 20ch;
}

.grid-left {
  grid-area: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.grid-center {
  grid-area: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.grid-right {
  grid-area: right;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.scanTitle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.checkboxes label {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.checkboxes label:first-of-type {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.requiredFieldLabel {
  border: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 2px;
  color: #333366;
  font-family: "verdana";
  font-size: small;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: right;
}

.requiredFieldLabel::before {
  content: "* ";
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="scanTitle">Employee Title</div>
  <form id="copysomeForm" action="/abc/employee.htm" method="POST">
    <div class="grid-top">
      <div>
        <label class="requiredFieldLabel">Employee ID</label>
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label class="requiredFieldLabel">Delay Reason for All Employees</label>
        <select id="reasonSelect" name="delayReason" onchange="reasonChanged()">
          <option value="">-No Selection-</option>
          <option value="Late Payment">Late Payment</option>
          <option value="Options Test One">Options Test One</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-left">
      <div>
        <div>
          <label
            ><input
              id="sendEmailAlert1"
              name="sendEmailAlert"
              type="checkbox"
            />Send Email</label
          >
        </div>
        <div><label>Subject:</label></div>
        <div>
          <input
            id="empSubject"
            name="empSubject"
            type="text"
            value=""
            size="35"
            maxlength="100"
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Message:</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <textarea
            id="empMessage"
            name="empMessage"
            rows="5"
            cols="35"
          ></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>CC:</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input
            id="empCC"
            name="empCC"
            type="text"
            value=""
            size="35"
            maxlength="100"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-center">
      <div>
        <label
          ><input id="topList" name="list1" type="checkbox" />Employee
          Sign</label
        >
      </div>
      <div class="checkboxes">
        <label
          ><input id="topList" name="list1" type="checkbox" />Employee
          Decision</label
        >
        <label><input id="list1" name="list2" type="checkbox" />Go Right</label>
        <label
          ><input id="list2" name="list3" type="checkbox" />Turn Off the
          Switch</label
        >
        <label><input id="list3" name="list4" type="checkbox" />Go Left</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <label>Note I</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <textarea id="empNote1" name="empNote1" rows="5" cols="35"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-right">
      <div>
        <div>
          <label>Note II:</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <textarea id="empNote2" name="empNote2" rows="5" cols="35"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <label>Comment:</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <textarea
            id="empComment"
            name="empComment"
            rows="5"
            cols="35"
          ></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label class="requiredFieldLabel">Tag</label>
        <select
          id="reasontagSelect"
          name="tagReason"
          onchange="reasonTagChanged()"
        >
          <option value="">-No Selection-</option>
          <option value="Tag1">Tag1</option>
          <option value="Tag2">Tag2</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. If I want to bring the  input text box of `Employee ID` and the dropdown list of `Delay Reason for All Employees` in a sam vertical line, as I've shown in the image of my post, then I would have to define another grid for this?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Do you want it to be alongside the other columns (so there's four), do you want to align it with one of the other columns, or something else?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I would like it to be like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpJGh.png
However, in your code, it's like  this:https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGvYm.png
As you can see the `Delay Reason for All Employees` text is pushing the drop down select list towards right. Please let me now if more clarification is needed.

Comment: Ah, you want to right-align them. Simple enough. I actually partially addressed this in my last bullet point, but I'll update my answer to be more clear and give the desired behavior.

Comment: I've made it so the "Employee ID" and "Delay Reason" are right-aligned. I'm not sure if "Employee Title" is meant to be involved; if so, please say how it fits in in relation to the rest and how it should be placed.

Comment: Thanks but for some reason, it's still showing like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SozBF.png and not like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpJGh.png

For Employee Title we can just leave a space between it and Employee ID which I believe we could accomplish using `margin-top` CSS property? Also, if I want to leave some space between all the left, right and center grid elements, this can be done using `grid-gap` property?

Comment: "it's still showing like this": yes, that's what I was asking. I believe you want "Employee Title" to be aligned with the inputs? Currently, it's not in the grid at all (almost identical to your original code), and so it is simply centered on the page.

Comment: "Also, if I want to leave some space between all the left, right and center grid elements, this can be done using grid-gap property?" Yes, it can; you can use `gap` to space all elements, or `column-gap` to only add space between columns.

Comment: `I believe you want "Employee Title" to be aligned with the inputs?` No. `Employee Title` is just a heading on the page. I just thought of having Employee ID and Delay Reason ... text like this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpJGh.png. So do I need to define a grid for this to achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: Oh, you want to right-align the labels themselves as well, i.e., make the input parts the same width?

Comment: `make the input parts the same width` I think that will work.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Is it working as expected now?

Comment: Thanks very much. Thats seems to be working as expected. I will test it in my actual code and let you know if issue arises.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253921/discussion-between-tan-and-darryl-noakes).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than changing the `float` of each individual element, put those elements in `<div>`s and use `float: left;` and `width: 33%` on each of those `<div>`s to make them columns. Try the snippet below (note: the snippet viewer is too small for 3 columns, so click the **Full Page** button to display it properly):

```css
.col {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
}

.scanTitle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

div.form {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

form {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: left;
}

.checkboxes label {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.checkboxes label:first-of-type {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.requiredFieldLabel {
  border: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 2px;
  color: #333366;
  font-family: "verdana";
  font-size: small;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: right;
}

.requiredFieldLabel::before {
  content: "* ";
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="scanTitle"> Employee Title</div>
  <div class="form">
    <form id="copysomeForm" action="/abc/employee.htm" method="POST">
      <div class="col">
        <div><label><input id="sendEmailAlert1" name="sendEmailAlert" type="checkbox" >Send Email</label></div>
        <div><label>Subject:</label></div>
        <div>
          <input id="empSubject" name="empSubject" type="text" value="" size="35" maxlength="100">
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Message:</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <textarea id="empMessage" name="empMessage" rows="5" cols="35"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>CC:</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input id="empCC" name="empCC" type="text" value="" size="35" maxlength="100">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col">

        <div>
          <label class="requiredFieldLabel">Employee ID</label>
          <input type="text" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label class="requiredFieldLabel">Delay Reason for All Employees</label>
          <select id="reasonSelect" name="delayReason" onchange="reasonChanged()">
            <option value="">-No Selection-</option>
            <option value="Late Payment">Late Payment</option>
            <option value="Options Test One">Options Test One</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div>


        </div>
        <div>
          <label><input id="topList" name="list1" type="checkbox">Employee Sign</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkboxes">
          <label><input id="topList" name="list1" type="checkbox">Employee Decision</label>
          <label><input id="list1" name="list2" type="checkbox">Go Right</label>
          <label><input id="list2" name="list3" type="checkbox">Turn Off the Switch</label>
          <label><input id="list3" name="list4" type="checkbox">Go Left</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div>
          <div>
            <label>Note I</label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <textarea id="empNote1" name="empNote1" rows="5" cols="35"></textarea>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <label>Note II:</label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <textarea id="empNote2" name="empNote2" rows="5" cols="35"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <label>Comment:</label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <textarea id="empComment" name="empComment" rows="5" cols="35"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label class="requiredFieldLabel">Tag</label>
          <select id="reasontagSelect" name="tagReason" onchange="reasonTagChanged()">
            <option value="">-No Selection-</option>
            <option value="Tag1">Tag1</option>
            <option value="Tag2">Tag2</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```